# Random Drawing on Hotspots

Tags: c#

I need a routine to get some random 2D vectors with higher probability to random spots. The spots can be rectangles as well. Please help me.

The function have to look like these

```
public Vector GetRandomHotSpotVectors(Vector minPosition, Vector maxPostion, int spotsCount, float minSpotSize, float maxSpotSize, int VectorCount);

var vectors = GetRandomHotSpotVectors(new Vector(0,0), new Vector(200,200), 2, 20, 30, 44);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static readonly Random Rand = new Random();        

    public static float NextFloat(float min, float max)
    {
        return min + ((float)Rand.NextDouble() * (max - min));
    }

    public static Vector4[] GetHotSpotVectors(
        Vector2 leftTop, 
        Vector2 rightBottom, 
        int spotsCount, 
        float minSpotSize, 
        float maxSpotSize,
        float minVectorObjSize,
        float maxVectorObjSize,
        int vectorCount)
    {
        var vectors = new Vector4[vectorCount];
        var vectorsProceeded = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i != spotsCount; i++)
        {
            var spotSize = NextFloat(minSpotSize, maxSpotSize);
            var left = NextFloat(leftTop.X, rightBottom.X - spotSize);
            var top = NextFloat(leftTop.Y, rightBottom.Y - spotSize);
            var right = left + spotSize;
            var bottom = top + spotSize;

            var currSpotCount = vectorCount / spotsCount;

            for (var j = vectorsProceeded; j < vectorsProceeded + currSpotCount; j++)
            {
                var vecObjSize = NextFloat(minSpotSize, maxVectorObjSize);
                vectors[j] = new Vector4(
                    NextFloat(left, right), 
                    NextFloat(top, bottom), 
                    vecObjSize, 
                    vecObjSize);
            }
            vectorsProceeded += currSpotCount;
        }

        return vectors;
    }
```